# Can I use wood from a camphor tree for a barbecue?

Tags: barbecue

I have some dry wood from a camphor tree in my garden. Is the wood suitable for open fire barbecue?

Comment: Do you mean the camphor laurel tree?

Comment: Yes it is a camphor laurel tree.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the wood is fast burning, which may not be ideal for a barbecue. Additionally, the wood will probably burn smelling of camphor, which could (will) give your food some of that taste.

I can't find anything related to the safety aspect, but several sources say not to eat things with camphor in them, and that breathing it in large doses can be toxic.

I probably wouldn't use it for that purpose.